# Can we push custom logs from function app (subscription A) into Log Analytic Workspace (subscription B)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to push custom logs from function app which is in subscription A into Log Analytic Workspace which is in subscription B.

I'm using the ARM template to push logs from function app(subscription A) to Log Analytic Workspace (subscription A) by using the below git link. Able to push logs into Log Analytic Workspace successfully.

https://github.com/MarcelMeurer/FunctionApp-to-LogAnalytics

But when trying to push from different subscriptions getting 400 bad request error.

Is it possible to push logs into Log Analytic Workspace when function app and Log Analytic Workspace are in different subscriptions?

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*Please check if below workaround helps to fix the issue*:

Not aware of ARM template but I tried using the portal to send the Function App Logs in Log Analytics Workspace from one subscription to another subscription.

I have notified that the Log Analytics Workspace should be in the same regions of your existing Log Analytics Workspace instance in both the subscriptions. Otherwise, it will fail to push/transfer when using CLI, PowerShell, ARM management tools and will not show the LA Workspace instances in the Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hari Krishna.. Thanks for ur answer. But I do not need azure function app resource logs .. I have logs stored in my local machine.. so I just want to push those custom logs by using azure function of subscription A into Log Analytic Workspace of subscription B. Is it feasible to do it?